# Wildcard character in ImageJ macros

Tags: macros, imagej

A quick and really simple one for someone I'm sure - but now me, sadly - is there a wildcard character I can use in conjunction with the selectwindow command which would allow me to match an unspecified character sequence as part of a name?

The IJ documentation I can unearth suggests that the * wildcard character only works with the close command. Not sure why, but it seems to be true.

Thanks very much for any help

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a wildcard character I can use in conjunction with the selectwindow command which would allow me to match an unspecified character sequence as part of a name?

Not in the macro language. But this sort of operation is easy using one of the supported scripting languages of [ImageJ2](http://imagej.net/).

Here is an example [Groovy](http://imagej.net/Groovy) script that activates the first window title matching the given [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

```
// @String regex(label = "Regex string for window title")

import ij.IJ
import ij.WindowManager

titles = WindowManager.getImageTitles()

for (title in titles) {
    if (title.matches(".*" + regex + ".*")) {
        IJ.selectWindow(title)
        break
    }
}
IJ.showMessage("No matching window")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is as close to a wildcard character for the ImageJ macro.

```
if(matches(Roi.getName(), ".*blo.*")) {

}
```